# Good eclipse IDE for javascript development with package manager

Tags: angularjs, eclipse, npm, gruntjs, bower

I have JavaScript/AngularJS project with bower as package manager and grunt as task manager. Which eclipse IDE will be good for this?

I tried eclipse neon , that has npm and bower install support. But there is no node.js in my project.

So how can I run my AngularJS project with bower/grunt in Eclipse IDE?

Comment: you are talking about the versions, I think you need to add the plugins to what ever eclipse version you have,if you need dedicated IDE give a try for WEBSTORM from jet brains

Comment: Neon is just the code name for the current release of Eclipse (4.6). There are many additional plugins available that you can install in that Eclipse including Nodeclipse which provides node.js support.